# English to Danish locale issue

Tags: android, locale

I have an activity that consists of textviews. I have made the activity compatible for English and Danish locales.

When i change the locale from English to Danish and select the app from app drawer, only some of the text views are getting converted to Danish locale. But when I re run the app from Eclipse all the textviews are getting converted to Danish.

Is this a bug that from onPause state of an activity the strings.xml is not getting referenced properly or is there any other solutuion to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I have checkboxes whose text is not getting changed immediately when we change the Locale.

So, on the onPause method of the activity I have assigned the values of the Strings again that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Might be because the activity hasn't been restarted. Try to kill the process and run it again from drawer.

Comment: Does that mean that everytime we change the locale, we need to restart the activity? And what might be the reason that only some textviews are getting updated and others doesn't.

Comment: Its a big thing to change the locale. Its more than just text reference, its the whole OS that needs to change references.
I would imagine that all textviews for each activity are similar, meaning 1 activity would only have english while another would only have danish. IF that is not the case: meaning for 1 activity you have both danish and english, well then I'm a little puzzled :)

Comment: I m puzzled too because all the text views have both the english and danish strings ataached in Strings.xml

Comment: @RahulVarma but is it within the same view of the same activity?

Comment: Yes. All the textViews are on same view embedded in a scrollview.

Comment: @RahulVarma that is kinda odd. But you should still be able to work around it by making sure to restart the activity.

Comment: @RahulVarma Just another question. Are you sure they have the same name? If the name of the strings don't match it will use the one that matches... so even though the language is set to danish it can't find the match in the strings and it'll use the one from english.